# Mobile cross platform development with c++ in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cross-platform

I saw that there is mobile cross platform development with c++ in visual studio 2015, but I cannot find any significant materials about it.
How to start and some docs about Android and iOS call APIs.

Can anyone suggest the right sources ???

Comment: Related: [Disadvantages of cross-platform mobile app development using Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33053056/514235).